# UIImagePicker that only fills the top half of the screen

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to present a camera on the only the top half of my screen and my code isn't resizing the camera properly. I'm trying to add a view to the top half of my screen and then have the camera's cameraOverlayView property conform to that view's frame. Regardless of what I try however, the camera still appears in full screen mode. If someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

```
    // Setting Up The Camera View

    cameraView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, view.bounds.width, view.bounds.width))
    view.addSubview(cameraView)

    // Setting Up The Camera

    var cam = UIImagePickerController()
    cam.delegate = self
    cam.allowsEditing = false
    cam.videoMaximumDuration = 7
    cam.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityType.TypeMedium
    cam.mediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypesForSourceType(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera)!
    cam.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
    cam.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice.Rear
    cam.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureMode.Video
    cam.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashMode.Off
    cam.showsCameraControls = true

    cam.cameraOverlayView = cameraView
    cam.cameraOverlayView?.frame = cameraView.frame

    camera = cam

    self.presentViewController(camera, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think what you want to do can be accomplished using a UIImagePickerController. The AVFoundation is what you want to use if you want complete customization of the camera. You can read about it here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW2.

P.S. It is not the simplest framework to use

Comment: Ok. Yeah I was trying to avoid AVFoundation, at least for the time being, haha. I guess i'll be jumping in to it though, unless someone else has a way to accomplish this with uiimagepicker. Thanks for the response!